How do I make so that my TABLE IV starts immediately starts right after the end of TABLE III?
How do I make so that my TABLE IV starts immediately starts right after the end of TABLE III?


Just place both tabular-like environments and their associated captions in a single table environment.

Judging from the image you post (without examples of code, you should add it), you're using IEEEtran.
There's no rule saying that a table environment must contain a single tabular: it can contain any material, including two (or more) tabulars with their captions. The only problem is that you're in charge of spacing them.
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{A caption for the first table}

\begin{tabular}{@{} cccc @{}}
\toprule
A & B & C & D \\
\midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\caption{A caption for the second table}

\begin{tabular}{@{} cccc @{}}
\toprule
A & B & C & D \\
\midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\lipsum[2-9]

\end{document}



There are a number of ways of achieving what you want, but the simplest is the following.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

You can see my tables, Table~\ref{tab:3} and Table~\ref{tab:4}. 

\begin{table}[!tbp]
  \centering
    \caption{Table III}
    \label{tab:3}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        A&B\\
        C&D\\
    \end{tabular}
    \bigskip
    \caption{Table IV}
    \label{tab:4}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        E&F\\
        G&H\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


If you are looking for other ways, you can take a look at Page 2-3 of this document.

The usual guideline is that tables should have fewer than average horizontal lines and no vertical lines.  I think you just broke some people.

@Teepeemm, of course. But that is not the issue here. That will be decided by the OP.
